# Using Npgsql ADO Entity Framework with jsonb

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, entity-framework-6

My test database is based on this

```
create table test 
(
    id int primary key, 
    b text, 
    i int, 
    name_1 text, 
    name_2 text, 
    alt_names jsonb
);
```

I've added `EntityFramework6.Npgsql` via nuget which looks like it included some dependencies

[image: Installed Nuget]

When I build the data model using database first I can see every column EXCEPT the `alt_names` jsonb column.

This page [Supported Types and their Mappings](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/basic.htm) suggests that jsonb is supported by default.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

when you pull directly as jsonb, it may not be obtained as desired or it may return as an error. Also, if I were you, I would create the view first. If you have problems, you can change the nuget.
Postgresql code:

```
create or replace view public.testview 
as select
t.id,
t.b,
t.i,
t.name_1,
t.name_2,
json_build_object('alt_names', t.alt_names) as alt_names
from test t;
```

c# code:

```
  using Npgsql;
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Net.Http;
  using System.Net.Http.Headers;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;
  namespace ConsoleApp1
  {
  class Program
  {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
          
          var cs = "Host=localhost;Username=postgres;Password=123456;Database=postgres";

          using var con = new NpgsqlConnection(cs);
          con.Open();

          var sql = "select * from public.testview";

          using var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, con);
          NpgsqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
          List<object> list = new List<object>();
          var i = 0;
          while (dr.Read())
          {
              while (i<dr.FieldCount)
              {
                  list.Add(dr[i]);
                  i++;
              }               
          }
          Console.WriteLine(list[5].ToString());
          //"{\"alt_names\" : \"test\"}"
      }


  }
  }
```

Comment: Are you suggesting not using the EntityFramework6? But go old school writing long hand SQL and creating custom class to hold the objects? I was hopping to avoid this, as although do able it requires more coding especially handling various data types, NULL's and Avoiding SQL injection.